# Laravel 5 VerifyCsrfToken mismatch on iPhone

Tags: laravel-5

Working on a responsive site and having trouble with VerifyCsrfToken middleware on Laravel 5.

Front-end is built on AngularJS and Laravel is serving the application.

On desktop, when I make a request to the API on Laravel, token from front-end request header is matching the token on Laravel session, so I get access to the API. However, on iPhone, these don't match.

I added some log statements to the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`  PHP class, so I check what's being passed to the class.

**Server log when requested from desktop:**

`[2015-03-04 18:18:07] local.INFO: request header token:
MVQ7u5fkjBTMRsM0GyOX0wuBcRwYMnWVsKDceQZ7

[2015-03-04 18:18:07] local.INFO: session token: MVQ7u5fkjBTMRsM0GyOX0wuBcRwYMnWVsKDceQZ7`

**Server log when requested from iPhone:**

`[2015-03-04 18:17:25] local.INFO: request header token:
hDIiwrPiM9r5XI6QPPp1DIvp6s7gqGDk5gg9Dqus

[2015-03-04 18:17:25] local.INFO: session token:
GvxO0zpTJzJsZ32hX5HHPtMxf7ex1bFEtmUWMlyV

[2015-03-04 18:17:25] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/planmons/laravel/tennis/storage/framework/compiled.php:2410`

This doesn't happen on XCode iOS Simulator, but only on the device.

I have no idea where to look/investigate further, so I will appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest looking at this tute for inspiration: http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs in particular the section titled: "Fetching Restricted Resources from the API Subdomain" which explains how to hit an API in L5 without being on same domain

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the same cause like your problem, but i found out that **disabled cookies** in the iOS browser will disable the possibility to have a session with PHP/Laravel5. Because of this the CsrfToken will be calculated new for the request, in our case POST `/auth/login`.

I solved this partially with a Middleware, that checks if a Session-Cookie is set when using POST/PUT/DELETE.